# How to close two forms loaded in memory , when one of them is closed?

Tags: c#

When I run my application 2 different forms are loaded simultaneously,but one of them is shown.Now I want If one of these form is closed ,other form which is hidden should get closed also.Any Suggestion.
No Parent -Child relation between these forms.

Comment: Are they both launched from the same process, or two different programs?

Comment: @keyboardP, Two different forms from the same application are loaded and are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the two forms are both in the same process, you can have the second hidden form handle the FormClosed event of the visible form and close it self when the Visible Form's FormClosed event fires.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // The following does not need to happen in the Load of this form

      // Create hidden Form
      Form2 frm = new Form2();

      // Attach hidden form to this form
      frm.AttachTo(this);
    }
  }

  public class Form2 : Form
  {
    public void AttachTo(Form frmMain)
    {      
      frmMain.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frmMain_FormClosed);
    }

    void  frmMain_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.Close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this is one application with reference to both forms. Let me know if this is not the case.

Given this assumption, you have the following (shown in pseudocode):

```
MyApplication
{
    Form form1;
    Form form2;
}
```

Each of the form's Close events can close the other form if it is not already closed:

```
Form1_Close()
{
    if(form2 != null)
    {
        form2.Close();
        form2 = null;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Form2_Close()
{
    if(form1 != null)
    {
        form1.Close();
        form1 = null;
    }
}
```

Does this meet your requirements?